# Custom design Text Box

Tags: android, textbox, textview, android-custom-view

[image: i want to design this text box with dynamic text]

I want to design above text box but not getting any idea how to do this.

i have search png,svg for above did not found any .

please help me out any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Using [`LayerDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) to achieve your text box design.

What is a `LayerDrawable` in simply?

> A LayerDrawable is a drawable object that manages an array of other
>   drawables. Each drawable in the list is drawn in the order of the
>   list—the last drawable in the list is drawn on top.
>
> Each drawable is represented by an  element inside a single
>    element.

From your text box design, I will divide into 4 elements.

- An arrow icon at the center horizontal at top
- A text box content in rectangle
- A top left image in bitmap
- A top right corner in bitmap

Put all in **background_text_box.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- The arrow in triangle by rotate a rectangle 45 degrees -->
    <item
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:top="0dp">
        <rotate android:fromDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FFF1A4" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>

    </item>

    <!-- The content in rectangle -->
    <item
        android:width="300dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF1A4" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- The left corner image in bitmap-->
    <item
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:top="5dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </item>

    <!-- The right corner image in bitmap -->
    <item
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:top="5dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The result looks like:

[image]

Let's test it:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="50dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Congratulation...!\nLaxminarayan is top performaer\nof month December 2017"
        android:background="@drawable/background_text_box"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The text box looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you thats all i want. save ma day thanks once again!!